# In Swift, how can I guarantee that only 1 task runs/wait at the most of the time?

Tags: swift

In Swift, I have a recursive function which I want it to be executed every minute. It looks something like below.

```
func someFunc() {
    // business logics...
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 60) {
        self.someFunc()
    }
}
```

The thing is that this `someFunc()` can be initiated by multiple callers, but I only want to allow **one** instance of someFunc() running or waiting to be executed in the future.

What is the best way to guarantee that at most 1 `someFunc()` will be running or queued at any given timeeeee?

(I am using Swift 5.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `NSLock` for this:

```swift
import PlaygroundSupport

let lock = NSLock()

func someFunc(msg: String) {
  guard lock.try() else { return }
  print(msg)
  DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
    lock.unlock()
    someFunc(msg: msg)
  }
}

someFunc(msg: "call1")
someFunc(msg: "call2") // Ignored
someFunc(msg: "call3") // Ignored

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean to keep track of the function call is queued (assuming you're not calling someFunc() from different threads)

```
var isQueued = false
func someFunc() {
    if isQueued { return }
    // business logics...

    isQueued = true
    DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 60) {
        self.isQueued = false
        self.someFunc()
    }
}
```

Example

```
class Example {
    var isQueued = false
    func someFunc(_ i: Int) {
        if isQueued { return }
        // business logics...
        if i > 500 {
            return
        }
        print(i)

        isQueued = true
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.isQueued = false
            self.someFunc(i * 10)
        }
    }
}

let t = Example()
t.someFunc(1)
sleep(2)
t.someFunc(2)
sleep(1)
t.someFunc(3)
sleep(1)
t.someFunc(4)
sleep(1)
t.someFunc(5)
```

prints

> 1
> 10
> 100
> 4
> 40
> 400